# C# application doesn't work at my PC

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I've saw several Thread about similar problems. But I couldn't find proper answers for my situation. Please Help.

I have a application(about 10,000 line) developed on my PC(Windows7 64bit). Target platform is x86, and .NET version is 4.5.2. **It is works fine when I run it on my PC in Visual Studio 2015 Debugging mode.** It is works fine too, when I make it setup package, and install on my 4 friend's PCs and test. (A- window7 32bit, B - windows vista 32bit, C - windows7 64bit, D - windowsXP 32bit)

Just on my PC and, E - windows XP 32 bit, It isn't work. 
On E, Installer isn't work. Error occur. **And on my PC, Installer works properly, Install is completed perfectly. But when I run it, it doesn't show window form. just show me hourglass, beside mouse pointer....**

All of tested PC have .NET 4.5.2, and up-to-date service pack.

Anyone know about this situation? Please Help.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is not supported on windows XP, only 4.0

Comment: Phiter Fernandes, Really thanks. Thanks to you, one of issue is over. How about my PC?

Comment: Could be that external libraries (if you are using any) are missing some required files that are not included in the library itself, but depend on.

Comment: The application shouldn't work on any windows xp machines...

Comment: @YoungHoonKim Hook into the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event and log any errors to a file and see if anything gets spit out.

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated, the .net version you used is not working on XP.
This kind of things happens to me, when i forgot to properly add image resources to the project, or if some path to a file is not dynamic.
Many of my colleagues usually use a path to images like M:\Images\bla.jpg, and when come to school, of course there is no M disk.

Of course my examples are pretty newbie, but usually when something is not working as its supposed to, check the trivial things first =D

I believe that you haven't handled an exception the right way (although in most cases you would get an error message, but it happend to me that it doesn't).

As others suggested you, try add a logging system to the application, maybe this could solve you out.

Sometimes it helps if you rebuild the solution or code analyse.

Good luck!